# X Window / VNC session recording

Tags: x11, vnc, recording

While I am aware of rfbproxy and ffmpeg's x11grab capability, all the examples online seem to be aimed at users wanting to record their own sessions. My usage model is to maintain a (reasonably) trustworthy audit record of remote access to a system.

My problem is how to reconcile the files these create with the session metadata (notably the authenticated username). If the recording is started from within the session then I can capture the username, although this will expose the invocation to the user (e.g. if done via an XDG autostart).

(logging the input events might be a viable alternative to full video recording)

If the start/stop of the recording is not invoked from the users session, then how do I synchronize the start/stop with the beginning/ed of the users session?

Users will be connecting to a Linux desktop (I've not started thinking about how Wayland fits in all this) via VNC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User "balanceofpain" on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/21fsu2/screen_capturing_software_for_entire_x_session/) suggests:

--

FFmpeg/avconv can do that. You'd have to start it as a different user so the person audited would be unable to interfere with it. The command will be similar to:

```
 avconv -f x11grab -s 1366x768 -r 25 -i :0.0 /tmp/out.mpg
```

Remember to allow this user access to X with `xhost +si:localuser:<auditorusername>`

--

Hence I could use XDG's autostart but seperate privileges with sudo (to prevent user killing task). The remaining question is whether the recording ends at the end of the session.